# What is the "scope" that gets passed to a $scope.$watch function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$scope.$watch(
    function(scope) {return scope.aNumber;},
    function(newValue, oldValue) {alert("Value changed");}
    );
});
```

What is the "scope" that $scope.$watch takes in its first function? (everything after this is extra info that is tangentially related). I know "scope" without the $ generally represent just a variable, as in the directive link function (scope, element, attributes, ngController), etc. However I have no idea where it "comes from" here. Clearly it's connected to the controller's $scope, but how?

Also, the official doc states "The watchExpression is called on every call to $digest() and should return the value that will be watched. (Since $digest() reruns when it detects changes the watchExpression can execute multiple times per $digest() and should be idempotent.)" So what's the advantage to doing the return function rather than just saying $scope.valueToWatch (which doesn't work for me, but I have seen people do it).

---

Plunk with working watch just for the hell of it, don't really need it for q:
http://plnkr.co/edit/y86Wr93xLIao3wTwVsT8?p=preview

For those reading with same q later:
Good article on $watch: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/watch-digest-apply.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply the same scope from which the `$watch` is being executed. The only advantage to using this one instead of `$scope` is that it avoids you a useless closure, but it does the same.

I'm not sure to understand your second question, but note that these are equivalent:

```
1. $scope.$watch(function(scope) { return scope.prop1.prop2; }, cb);
2. $scope.$watch(function() { return $scope.prop1.prop2; }, cb);
3. $scope.$watch('prop1.prop2', cb);
```

Comment: edit: Why does scope need to be passed in? Is "scope" a keyword here somehow? edit 2: Looks like I can just do function(x){return x.myVar}. Is there some sort of general convention here, or is this a peculiarity of $watch?

Comment: It doesn't, angular just give it to you in case you find it convenient but you can avoid using it. I've updated my answer, see how `1.` and `2.` do the same

Comment: Thanks flori. I think I got it.

Comment: Also: don't get confused as why sometimes scopes are written $scope or the like, all the scopes are the same but you can name them as you want *except* in a controller because the name of parameters matters (so angular can inject these dependencies, that's a bit counter intuitive)

Comment: Merci! Looks like I have a lot to think about. I didn't even imagine this would work (tried it based on your example) -  $scope.$watch(
  $scope.aNumber.aSecondNumber, 
  alert("Value changed")
  );

I don't see why angular doesn't think that ".aSecondNumber" is a property of "aNumber" here. Ah well, will think about it some other time. Thank you again.

Comment: `$scope.$watch( $scope.aNumber.aSecondNumber, cb)` doesn't make sense: the first parameter of `$watch` should either be a string (example 3) or a function (example 1 and 2). Here you are trying to give it whatever is inside `$scope.aNumber.aSecondNumber`, be careful.