# How to get $watch to react to typeahead?

Tags: angularjs

$watch doesn't seem to catch the value changing when it's changed by a typeahead selection. I want it to react to changes...

```
  $scope.vm = 1; 
  $scope.$watch(function() { return $scope.vm }, alert('hi') );

<input type="text" ng-model="$scope.vm " typeahead="item as item.description for item in items  | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control"/>
```

[PLUNK](http://plnkr.co/edit/c0qei4PK5fcWMEuTxDOc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument of `$watch` is a function. You are executing the function immediately and then passing what ever the result of `alert` is to `$watch` (don't remember but probably null or undefined). You need to wrap it:

```
  $scope.vm = 1; 
  $scope.$watch(function() { return $scope.vm }, 
                function(newValue, oldValue) { alert('hi'); } );
```

*Edit*

You do you not need to include the `$scope` variable in your html, it should just be `vm`. Scope is implicitly applied to the mark up.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that doesn't solve it: http://plnkr.co/edit/c0qei4PK5fcWMEuTxDOc?p=preview Also, I think you can just write the cb without putting in a function, examples here, if you are interested (floribon's reply):  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640386/what-is-the-scope-that-gets-passed-to-a-scope-watch-function

Comment: Doesn't work. I added a test watch just to demonstrate that $watch works in my sample code overall: http://plnkr.co/edit/c0qei4PK5fcWMEuTxDOc

Comment: I don't understand why you have the javascript in two places? You only made a fix in one (which I don't think even gets executed., you need to fix the `example.js` file too. Also yes you can use callbacks, but in your case you have not provided it a callback you are just providing the result of a method call.

Comment: Javascript in one place now. I edited a bootstrap Ui example a bit. Cleaned it up with your suggestions: http://plnkr.co/edit/c0qei4PK5fcWMEuTxDOc?p=preview

Comment: You still have `ng-model="$scope.vm"`

Comment: That was it. Works: http://plnkr.co/edit/c0qei4PK5fcWMEuTxDOc?p=preview Thank you, and I apologize for being obstinate.

Answer (score 2):

You have `ng-model="$scope.vm"` when it should just be `vm` and as paulpdaniels said you need to wrap the `alert` in your listener callback.

Also, you might find passing a handler method to the  `typeahead-on-select` attribute is cleaner than putting `$watch` functions in your controllers.

**html**

`<input type="text" ng-model="vm" typeahead-on-select="change(vm)" typeahead="item as item.description for item in items  | filter:$viewValue | limitTo`:8" class="form-control"/>

**controller**

```
$scope.change = function(vm){
   console.log('vm', vm);
}
```

Comment: Dropped the $scope - that's actually from angular ui-boostrap's example. But anyway, made no diff: http://plnkr.co/edit/c0qei4PK5fcWMEuTxDOc

Comment: you still have `ng-model="$scope.vm"` in that plunk.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Sorry, should have found that myself.

Comment: Have you tried using the `typeahead-on-select` attribute that's available with the typehead directive? It might be cleaner to use that than adding `$watch` functions to your controller which is often a code smell. Just a thought.

Comment: I have,  and should, was just avoiding passing functions to the directive. But really, I am probably about to redo it that way. Thanks for the help again.